# Image insert error

Tags: php, html

I am using a php script, and yes im aware that its using outdated mysql coding.  Its in my schedule to update the coding on the site herein the near future, however i have an issue with my uploads of images that i cant seem to sort.  It worked just fine when I built the script, now it just stopped working.  I have scanned over the coding many times and just cant find the error.  Im sure im just over looking it, but maybe not?

input code:

```
include 'db_connect4.php';

mysql_select_db("db#########", $con);

echo "<h2 style='margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 20px;'>Home Page</h2>";

if($nt == "upd"){
    echo "<font style='color: #f00; float: right;'>SITE UPDATED<br />$date $time</font>";
}
elseif($nt == "cnl"){
    echo "<font style='color: #f00; float: right;'>CHANGES CANCELED<br />$date $time</font>";
}
else{}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='title' && loc='Home'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<p style='margin-left:25px;'><b>Page Title</b> <br /><input type='text' name='title' value='$row[3]' style='margin-left: 20px;'></p>"; }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='welcome' && loc='Home'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<p style='margin-left:25px;'><b>Welcome Paragraph Title</b> <br /><input type='text' name='welcome' value='$row[3]' size='50' style='margin-left: 20px;'></p>"; }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='welcome_message' && loc='Home'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<font style='margin-left:25px;'><b>Welcome Paragraph</b></font>
    <div style='margin-left: 45px;'>
        <textarea id='textarea1' name='welcome_message' style='height: 250px; width: 600px;'>
               $row[3]
        </textarea></div>"; }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='services' && loc='Home'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<p style='margin-left:25px;'><b>Services List Title</b> <br /><input type='text' name='services' value='$row[3]' size='50' style='margin-left: 20px;'></p>"; }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='services_list' && loc='Home'");
echo "<p style='margin-left:25px;'><b>Services List</b> ";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<br /><input type='text' name='services_list_$row[0]' value='$row[3]' size='30' style='margin-left: 20px;'>"; }
echo "</p>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='service' && loc='Home'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<p style='margin-left:25px;'><b>Services Photo Section Title</b> <br /><input type='text' name='service' value='$row[3]' size='50' style='margin-left: 20px;'></p>"; }

echo "<table width='100%' border='0'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_info WHERE nm='serv1' && loc='Home'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  echo "<td align='center'><img src='$row[3]' height='$row[4]px' width='$row[5]px'><br /><input type='file' name='serv1'></td>"; }
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_info WHERE nm='serv2' && loc='Home'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  echo "<td align='center'><img src='$row[3]' height='$row[4]px' width='$row[5]px'><br /><input type='file' name='serv2'></td>"; }
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_info WHERE nm='serv3' && loc='Home'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  echo "<td align='center'><img src='$row[3]' height='$row[4]px' width='$row[5]px'><br /><input type='file' name='serv3'></td>"; }
    echo "</tr><tr>";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='serv1b' && loc='Home'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  echo "<td align='center'><textarea name='serv1b' cols='50' rows='5'>$row[3]</textarea></td>"; }
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='serv2b' && loc='Home'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  echo "<td align='center'><textarea name='serv2b' cols='50' rows='5'>$row[3]</textarea></td>"; }
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='serv3b' && loc='Home'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  echo "<td align='center'><textarea name='serv3b' cols='50' rows='5'>$row[3]</textarea></td>"; }
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='news' && loc='Home'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<p style='margin-left:25px;'><b>Company News Title</b> <br /><input type='text' name='news' value='$row[3]' size='50' style='margin-left: 20px;'></p>"; }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_info WHERE nm='testimonials' && loc='Home'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<p style='margin-left:25px;'><b>Testimonials Title</b> <br /><input type='text' name='testimonials' value='$row[3]' size='50' style='margin-left: 20px;'></p>"; }

echo "<hr style='width: 100%; height: 5px; background: #000; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;' />";

echo "<h3 style='margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 20px;'>Photo Slide Show</h3>";

echo "<table width-='100%' style='margin-left: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;'>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY nm DESC LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){$q = substr("$row[1]", 6, 10); $r = ++$q; $galnm = "image $r";}

echo "<tr><td><b>Image Description</b> <br /><input type='text' name='galtxt' value='$row[3]' size='50' style='margin-left: 20px;'></td><td><b>Image</b> <br /><input type='file' name='serv4' id='serv4'><input type='hidden' name='galnm' value='$galnm'></td></tr>";

echo "</table>";

echo "<table width-='100%' style='margin-left: 25px;' cellpadding='5px;' cellspacing='5px'>";

echo "<tr><td valign='top' width='5%' align='center'><font style='color:#f00; font-size:large; font-weight:bold;'>X</font></td>
      <td valign='top' width='50%'><font style='font-size: large; font-weight: bold;'>Photo</font></td>
      <td valign='top' width='45%'><font style='font-size: large; font-weight: bold;'>Photo Information</font></td>
";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){$a = substr("$row[3]", 7, 100);
    echo "<tr><td valign='top' width='5%'  align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]' value='$row[0]' style='border: solid 1px #000;'></td>
      <td valign='top' width='50%' align='center' style='background: #C0C0C0;'><img src='http://www.sunwellservice.biz/$row[3]' height='190' width='470' style='border: solid 1px #000;'></td>
      <td valign='top' width='45%'><b>Image Name</b><br />$a<br /><br /><b>Image Description </b><br />$row[4]
";
}

echo "</table>";

echo "</form>";
```

INSERT CODING:

```
        $a = $_POST['title'];
        $b = $_POST['welcome'];
        $c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['welcome_message']);
        $d = $_POST['services'];
        $e = $_POST['services_list_4'];
        $f = $_POST['services_list_5'];
        $g = $_POST['services_list_6'];
        $h = $_POST['services_list_7'];
        $az = $_POST['services_list_8'];
        $j = $_POST['services_list_9'];
        $k = $_POST['services_list_127'];
        $l = $_POST['services_list_128'];
        $m = $_POST['service'];
        $n = $_POST['serv1'];
        $o = $_POST['serv2'];
        $p = $_POST['serv3'];
        $r = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['serv1b']);
        $s = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['serv2b']);
        $t = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['serv3b']);
        $u = $_POST['news'];
        $v = $_POST['testimonials'];
        $w = $_POST['galtxt'];

        $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

        if($w == TRUE){
            $aa = $_FILES["serv4"]["name"];
            $bb = $_POST['galtxt'];
            $cc = $_POST['galnm'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (nm, loc, txt) VALUES ('$cc', 'Home', '$bb')";

            mysql_query($sql);

            $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

            $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["serv4"]["name"]));
        if ((($_FILES["serv4"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["serv4"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["serv4"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["serv4"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
        && ($_FILES["serv4"]["size"] < 2000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($_FILES["serv4"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["serv4"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {

            if (file_exists("../front/images/" . $_FILES["serv4"]["name"]))
              {
              echo $_FILES["serv4"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["serv4"]["tmp_name"],
              "../front/images/" . $_FILES["serv4"]["name"]);
            mysql_query("UPDATE gallery SET src='images/$aa' WHERE nm='$cc' AND loc='Home'");
            echo $aa;
              }
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
          }
        }
        else{}


        $checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];
        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id='$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);}

        if($n == TRUE){
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["serv1"]["name"]));
        if ((($_FILES["serv1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["serv1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["serv1"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["serv1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
        && ($_FILES["serv1"]["size"] < 2000000))
          {
          if ($_FILES["serv1"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["serv1"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {

            if (file_exists("../front/images/" . $_FILES["serv1"]["name"]))
              {
              echo $_FILES["serv1"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["serv1"]["tmp_name"],
              "../front/images/" . $_FILES["serv1"]["name"]);
            mysql_query("UPDATE image_info SET path='images/$n' WHERE nm='serv1' AND loc='Home'");
              }
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
          }
        }
        else{}

        if($o == TRUE){ 
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["serv2"]["name"]));
        if ((($_FILES["serv2"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["serv2"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["serv2"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["serv2"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
        && ($_FILES["serv2"]["size"] < 2000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($_FILES["serv2"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["serv2"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {

            if (file_exists("../front/images/" . $_FILES["serv2"]["name"]))
              {
              echo $_FILES["serv2"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["serv2"]["tmp_name"],
              "../front/images/" . $_FILES["serv2"]["name"]);
              mysql_query("UPDATE image_info SET path='images/$o' WHERE nm='serv2' AND loc='Home'");
              }
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
          }
          }
        else{}

        if($p == TRUE){
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["serv3"]["name"]));
        if ((($_FILES["serv3"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["serv3"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["serv3"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["serv3"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
        && ($_FILES["serv3"]["size"] < 2000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($_FILES["serv3"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["serv3"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {

            if (file_exists("../front/images/" . $_FILES["serv3"]["name"]))
              {
              echo $_FILES["serv3"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["serv3"]["tmp_name"],
              "../front/images/" . $_FILES["serv3"]["name"]);
              mysql_query("UPDATE image_info SET path='images/$p' WHERE nm='serv3' AND loc='Home'");
              }
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
          }
        }
        else{}

        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$a' WHERE nm='title' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$b' WHERE nm='welcome' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$c' WHERE nm='welcome_message' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$d' WHERE nm='services' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$e' WHERE nm='services_list' AND loc='Home' AND id='4'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$f' WHERE nm='services_list' AND loc='Home' AND id='5'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$g' WHERE nm='services_list' AND loc='Home' AND id='6'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$h' WHERE nm='services_list' AND loc='Home' AND id='7'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$az' WHERE nm='services_list' AND loc='Home' AND id='8'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$j' WHERE nm='services_list' AND loc='Home' AND id='9'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$k' WHERE nm='services_list' AND loc='Home' AND id='127'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$l' WHERE nm='services_list' AND loc='Home' AND id='128'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$m' WHERE nm='service' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$r' WHERE nm='serv1b' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$s' WHERE nm='serv2b' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$t' WHERE nm='serv3b' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$u' WHERE nm='news' AND loc='Home'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE page_info SET txt='$v' WHERE nm='testimonials' AND loc='Home'");

        $nm = $_GET['nm'];
        $loc = $_GET['loc'];

        echo"
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            <!--
            window.location = 'site.php?act=edit&nm=".$nm."&loc=".$loc."&nt=upd'
            //-->
        </script>";
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Quick and dirty redefined

Comment: I dont get any errors on the code.. The code may not look productive in the small picture, however if you saw the other 1200 lines of coding for the page then you would understand a little more.

Comment: There is one issue I get, the input into the DB for path, is "images/array".  The problem is that there is not array defined only a variable pulling data from the image.